# JS: Passing a scope as argument, binding it to a function that will be returned

Tags: javascript, function, scope, return, bind

Is it possible to define a function in the scope of a parent function and bind an argument passed through the parent function as its scope before returning it?

Here is an example:

```
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar"
};

var myFunction = (function() {
    return function() {
        return this.foo;
    };
}).call(myObject);

myFunction.call(myObject); // I'd like to bind myObject as this does ...

myFunction(); // ... but I'd like to do it before invoking it, without .call() or .apply()
```

Or another complex example, that describes what I'm trying to do:

```
var createMyCopy = function(original, self) {
    var copy;

    eval("copy=" + original.toString());

    console.log(copy()); // returns undefined
};

(function() {
    var self = "Hello world",
        myFunction = function() {
            return self;
        };

    console.log(myFunction()); // returns "Hello world"

    createMyCopy(myFunction);
})();
```

I'm trying to create a copy of a function, so that I can make changes to it without changing the original one, but I'd like to have the variables that are defined in the original one in the copy as well...

Comment: What do you mean by making changes to a function?

Comment: I think you need to describe your *final* goal. Your second example hardly seems related to the first. Are you trying to bind the calling context, or is it actually the variables in scope that you need?

Comment: ...FYI, you defined a `self` parameter in the `createMyCopy` function, but passed nothing to it. If you do `createMyCopy(myFunction, self);`, it works, though sort of doubt this is going to be a good approach.

Comment: My English is not that good, so it is hard for me, sorry. I am trying to get the variable in the scope of the new function created with eval. I tried and don't get it so I thought binding the old variable as this in the scope of the new function would be an alternative. But the second example is my final goal.

Comment: Yes but your goal doesn't make any sense.. you are trying to create a copy of a function so you can change it without affecting original one... but there is no way to change a function in the first place.

Comment: @amnotiam OMG, that's it. I simply overlooked that!

Comment: @Esailija: If I do `myFunction.foo = "bar";` I changed the original one (or its object) and I don't want that. I'm trying to do something like a function/object hybrid constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar"
};

var myFunction = (function() {
    var self = this;
    return function() {
        return self.foo;
    };
}).call(myObject);
```

I think you're getting scope and context mixed up in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you mean this:

```
var myFunction = (function(obj) {
    return function() {
        return obj.foo;
    };
})(myObject);
```

The *immediately invoked function expression* is passed `myObject` and returns a new function in which that parameter is bound as the variable `obj`.

Comment: Yes, that's close to what I'm looking for but it does not work on a copy made with `eval()`...

Comment: @headacheCoder ah, you're using `eval` too?!  _Now_ I understand your pseudonym...

Comment: Don't be that insulting. There is AFAIK no alternative to eval in this case. I know that eval is "evil" but I need to use it.

Comment: @headacheCoder it was supposed to be humorous, not insulting.  But your updated question **did** give me a headache!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean, but you can do this:

```
var myObject = {
    foo: "bar"
};
function myFunction() {
    return this.foo;
}
console.log(myFunction.apply(myObject)); // bar
```

The first argument of `apply` is the `context` (ie. what `this` refers to). The second argument of `apply` is an array of arguments (but I've omitted that here as there are no arguments).

Comment: The code comment in the question states *"without .call() or .apply()"*. OP uses `.call()` in the question.